# Function is not displayed correctly in matplotlib

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

I want to visualize a function that is discontinuous at a certain value of x (=2).

However I do not get what I hoped.  My code is the following:

```
x = np.arange(-1, 4, 0.1)
y = 2 * x**2 / (x - 2)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x  , "y" : y})

% matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Set up the graph
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xticks(np.arange(-1,4, 0.5))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-8, 8, 0.5))
plt.axhline()
plt.axvline()
plt.grid()

# Plot the function
plt.plot(df["x"], df["y"], color='red')
axes = plt.gca()
xmin = -1
xmax = 4
ymin = -8
ymax = 8
axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
axes.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
plt.axvline(2)
plt.show()
```

What I get is the following:

[image]

Why the y values for x > 2 do not appear?

Comment: Have you tried using a larger `ymax` than `8`? For `x > 2`, the minimum `y` value seems to be `16`, so it simply doesn't fit within the limits you've chosen, it's there but it's off-screen

Comment: This is not a programming problem. If you want to look at the sine function at y values bigger 2 you would equally just not see anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. Trying to look at a function outside the range where its values lie could be a math problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've set your `ylim` in such a way that it cuts off the values for x > 2.

Consider the output of your function for inputs greater than 2:

```
f = lambda x: 2 * x**2 / (x - 2)
print([f(i) for i in np.arange(2.1, 4, 0.2)])
#[88.199999999999918, 35.266666666666644, 24.999999999999989, 20.828571428571422,
# 18.688888888888883, 17.472727272727269, 16.753846153846151, 16.333333333333332,
# 16.105882352941176, 16.010526315789473]
```

If you changed the `ylim` constraints, you'll see the plot below:

```
# Set up the graph
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
#plt.xticks(np.arange(-1,4, 0.5))
#plt.yticks(np.arange(-8, 8, 0.5))
plt.axhline()
plt.axvline()
plt.grid()

# Plot the function
plt.plot(df["x"], df["y"], color='red')
axes = plt.gca()
xmin = -1
xmax = 4
ymin = -8
ymax = 100
axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
axes.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
plt.axvline(2)
plt.show()
```

[image: Sample output]